# Android sqlite Data not being inserted in database

Tags: android, sqlite

The data that is fetched from a server in json format. The data fetched is  stored into arraylists. The arraylists are looped through and stored into the database. The data does get retrieved and stored into the arrayLists I have confirmed by printing them out. Whats weird is in the init method there is a `getNumberOfEntries` method which returns 26 BUT `getNumberOfEntries` returns 0 if I call it after calling `init()`.

This is the method that loops through the arraylist

```
private void init()
{
    db      = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbHelper.dropTable(db);

    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbHelper.createTable(db);

    final SQLiteDatabase db;
    final long           numEntries;

    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    numEntries  = dbHelper.getNumberOfEntries(db);
    if(numEntries == 0)
    {
        db.beginTransaction();

        try
        {
            for (int i=0; i < courseNameArrayList.size(); i++)
            {
                dbHelper.insertCourses(db,
                                        courseTermArrayList.get(i),
                                        courseNumberArrayList.get(i),
                                        courseNameArrayList.get(i),
                                        courseDescriptionArrayList.get(i));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "init exception");
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "In Finally init");
            final long numEntries2  = dbHelper.getNumberOfEntries(db);
            Log.d(TAG, "init finally num entries: " + numEntries2);    // HERE IT LOGS AS 26 ENTRIES 
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }
    db.close();
}
```

This is the insertCourses method that gets called. I believe the problem is in this code

```
public void insertCourses(final SQLiteDatabase db,
                          final String         term,
                          final String         courseNumber,
                          final String         courseName,
                          final String         courseDescription)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Inserting Courses" + " " + term + " " + courseNumber + " " + courseName +
            " " + courseDescription);
    final ContentValues contentValues;

    contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_TERM, term);
    contentValues.put(COL_COURSE_NUM, courseNumber);
    contentValues.put(COL_COURSE_NAME, courseName);
    contentValues.put(COL_COURSE_DESCRIPTION, courseDescription);
   try
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "In insertCourses try");
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "In insertCourses catch");

        String exception = e.getMessage();
        Log.d(TAG, exception);
    }

}
```

getNumberOfEntries method

```
public long getNumberOfEntries(final SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Get Number of Entries");
    final long numEntries;

    numEntries = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME);
    return (numEntries);
}
```

Table structure

```
private static final String     CREATE_COURSE_INFO_TABLE    =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "  +
        TABLE_NAME                  + " ( " +
        COL_ID                      + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COL_TERM                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        COL_COURSE_NUM              + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        COL_COURSE_NAME             + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        COL_COURSE_DESCRIPTION      + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
```

Comment: Did you have logcat? The warning message is your error

Comment: Sorry I dont completely understand. Are you asking if I had any warnings in the output? No I did not have any warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second time returns 0 because the transaction is rolled back and then the rows are not inserted.

You should use this pattern.

```
   db.beginTransaction();
   try {
     ...
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
     db.endTransaction();
   }
```